# the behavior of returned function by binding console.log to console in the context of a child process

Tags: javascript, bind, child-process

```js
p = require('child_process').spawn('sleep', ['100']);

//cp.on('exit', ()=>{console.log('exited')});
cp.on('exit', console.log.bind(console,'exited'));

//cp.on('close',()=> {console.log('closed')});
cp.on('close',console.log.bind(console,'closed'));

setTimeout(()=>{cp.kill()}, 500)
```

when I run the code with node, the output is:

```
exited null SIGTERM
closed null SIGTERM
```

I know `bind` returns a new function with the first argument as its `this` context and the rest of them as its parameters.

if I replace commented lines with the line below them, there will be no `null SIGTERM` in the output. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `bind()`, the arguments you supply are inserted before any arguments provided by the caller. When `child_process` calls the `exit` and `close` event handlers, it passes the process's termination reason as the argument. Since `console.log()` prints all its arguments, this reason it printed after the value that you used in the `bind()` call.

It's roughly equivalent to this:

```
cp.on('exit', (...args) => console.log('exited', ...args));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant the opposite, the commented lines will just print `exited` and `closed` in the output, while the not commented lines will print `exited null SIGTERM` and `closed null SIGTERM`.

This happens because `console.log` is a [variadic](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1035417/Variadic-Functions-In-JavaScript) JavaScript function, this means it accepts an indefinite number of parameters and it will show all of them in the output:

```
console.log('a', 42, {});
```

When you use `console.log.bind(console, 'exited')`, it will create a new function that has `console` as `this` and `exited` as the first parameter. You can eventually call this function with other parameters:

```
const fn = console.log.bind(console, 'Hello')
fn('World!') // it will print 'Hello, World!'
```

If you pass this newly created function as the callback of `cp.on`, the parameters of the callback will be added just after the single parameter that you inserted.

On the other hand, if you pass `() => console.log('exited')` as the callback of `cp.on`, the parameters of the callback will be ignored, and you will always receive `exited` in the output.

If you want the `bind` complementary behaviour, you can use the spread operator:

```
cp.on('close',(...params)=> {console.log('closed', ...params)});
```

Comment: based on [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#event-close) first argument of the 'close' `event` handler is: "The exit code if the child exited on its own."

Comment: Thank you, to be honest I searched and I didn't find the doc when I wrote this answer, and in my memory I believed the first parameter was the error

Comment: I removed the paragraph where I talked about `cp.on` because misleading :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar Said the `bind()` inserts before the caller returning any argument in form of any data or code. 
Usually it Returns a reference to the **EventEmitter**, so that calls can be chained.You can use `emitter.prependListener()` method to add the event listener to the beginning of the listeners array.

What you can do something like below

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on('exit', () => console.log('value1'));
emitter.prependListener('exit', () => console.log('value2'));
emitter.emit('exit');
```

The Above program prints in the following order

```
Output:
value2
value1
```

Or you can invoke a anonymous function like this way 
`child.on("foo",()=> console.log("BLA"))`